# Making a template parameter as friend of template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I am debugging an application which interacts with third party library whose code is not available only header and .so are available. Now I can load it into debugger and check variable values of private member of class declared in third party library but since number of objects are huge, I want to create some mechanism to print it on console which I can analyse later. 
I came up with something like this

ThirdPartyHeader

```
class A
{
    private:
    int i;
};
```

I have not included extra details in above class

Debugprinter.cpp

```
#include <thirdpartheaders>

template <typename T> class debugprinter
{
    friend class T;
    public :
    void printonconsole()
    {
        T a;
        std::cout << std::endl << a.i << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to compile above this but it seems that I can't declare undefined type T as friend to my template class and get this error

**Error: i is not accessible from x::acc()**

Now I can resolve this problem by creating non template debugprinter   but just out of curiosity is there a way I can create a template class which would be friend to it's input type parameter?

Thanks

Comment: If you can't modify `A` to have `debugprinter` as a friend, there is no standard solution to access `A`'s private members. All the techniques you could use are Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is that as others mentioned friendship is not symmetric and you are attempting the wrong direction (granting `A` access to `debugprinter<A>`. That being said, and just for the sake of people searching through questions:

In the old version of the standard (C++03) it was impossible to directly declare a template argument as a friend. That restriction was lifted in C++11, although it requires a slightly different syntax:

```
template <typename T>
class test {
   friend T;             // note, not 'friend class T'!!!
};
```

Still, in C++03 you could achieve the same behavior by using one extra level of indirection. You cannot befriend a template argument, but you can befriend a dependent type, and by using an `identity` meta-function you could achieve what you wanted:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
   typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
class test {
   friend class identity<T>::type;
};
```

Comment: Do you know what the rational for the standards committee was to allow `friend T` but not `friend class T`? I can't see any (obvious) reason, why the compiler wouldn't be able to figure out the other syntax, too.

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't help to declare `A` as a friend of `debugprinter<A>`. The `friend` relation is not symmetric. The relation is only one-way. You would need `debugprinter<A>` to be a friend of `A` if you want to access private members of `A`. For that you need to modify the class `A` itself.

It is like with real-world friendship. You can't force somebody else to be your friend. You can only yourself behave friendly to others.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `T` as a friend, but it won't do you any good. What's needed is a way for your template to get at the private data in `T`, and that goes the other way around: `T` would have to declare your template as a friend. Decisions about friendship are made by the class that's offering friendship; it can't be demanded from another class. Without a friend declaration, there's no legitimate way to get at a class's private parts from outside; that's what private means.

Comment: No I can't declare T as friend class of templated class as friend declaration needs elaborated type specifier

Comment: But the reason for the error message you get is not that the friend declaration does not work, but that even if it worked, it would not help you.